# How to check whether the function has called or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

For example my code is like below.

I would like to classchange by clicking and hovering.

But it didn't work.

I would like to know,

① How to check the wrong point?

② How to fix such wrong point?

I tried `console.log`,but I would like to know whether the function is `correctly mapped` and 
`correctly work`.

Thanks

```js
var $ = jQuery;
const $days = $(this).find('.day');

function register() {

  function clicked() {
        $(this).toggleClass(is-clicked);
   }
  
  function hoverRange(){
      $(this).addClass(is-hover);
  }
  
  $days.on({
    click: clicked,
    hover: hoverRange,
  });
  
 }
  
 $("#calendar").each(register);
```

```css
td{
padding:10px;
border:solid  black 1px;}

table{
border-collapse:collapse;}

is-clicked{
background-color:aqua;
}

is-hover{
background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>

<div id=calendar>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class=day>1</td>
      <td class=day>2</td>
      <td class=day>3</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're using wrong code in the `click` event

1. you should have `.` in your css class.
2. you should use `this` when event is triggered, you were trying to trigger by using `$days` which is not correct.
3. for `hover` you don't need to write a method for that, I have updated the code.

```js
var $ = jQuery;
const $days = $(this).find('.day');

function register() {
  function clicked() {
    alert("clicked");
    $(this).toggleClass('is-clicked');
  }

  $(this).on({
    click: clicked
  });
}
$("#calendar").each(register);
```

```css
td {
  padding: 10px;
  border: solid black 1px;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.is-clicked {
  background-color: aqua;
}

td:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>

<div id=calendar>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class=day>1</td>
      <td class=day>2</td>
      <td class=day>3</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering ! I would like to know the difference of `$(this)` and `$days`.What causes problem by using `$days`?

Comment: `this` is a keyword and `$days` is the custom variable.